# How auto increment in a table?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and I have a table with 3 columns:

```
page_id title content
```

In page_id column, I check AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY. 
After inserting to this column it looks something like this:

```
1
2
3
...
```

but if I delete the second line for example, I get:

```
1
3
...
```

Why?
I want when I remove the second line, for example, to get:

```
1
2
...
```

and the id is updated automatically.
How can I fix that?

thank's

Comment: Don't worry about it. Non-consecutive ids is a completely normal occurrence

Answer (score 0):

Preserving the index after deleting a row is a way to **maintain correct links if another table has foreign keys pointing to this table**. Edit: As stated in the comments,: *if it works, there’s no need to fix it.*

If you really want to achieve reordering of your primary key, first backup your db data, then you may use a query such as:

```
SET @id = 0;
UPDATE `table` SET `table`.`page_id` = @id:= @id + 1;
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

***Be careful*** however that this will beak things if you **do** have other tables relying on page_id values. If that is the case, you must update those links as well, for example using the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` referential action. Please do read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) **before** taking such action